# Is there any way to specify line-height and margin based on the font size of the body?

Tags: css, font-size

A straight-forward css question. Let's say we have this styles:

```
  body { 
    font-size : 16px;
  }

  p {
   font-size : 0.875em; // relative to parent, 14px
   line-height : 1em; //relative to this element, 14px
   margin-bottom : 1em; //relative to this element, 14px
  }
```

This will mean that `<p>`s will have a font-size of 14px, a line-height of 14px and a margin-bottom of 14px.

What I would like is the equivalent of:

```
body : {
  font-size : 16px;
}

p { 
  font-size : 0.875em; // relative to parent, 14px;
  line-height : 1em; // relative to parent line-height, 16px;
  margin-bottom : 1em; // relative to parent margin-bottom, 16px;
}
```

The reason I want this is because I want to have a responsive font size which respects its baseline.

Comment: You'd like to have a line-height that depends on the line-height of parent?

Comment: use javascript to get the font size, and then do your math and set the line height & margin. or just hardcode it if the font size is not dynamic

Comment: @Giovanni Yes that's what I want. And a margin bottom if possible.

Comment: @Ace, the reasoning behind this is to have a responsive font baseline. Restyling with javascript would kill a mobile browser.

Comment: i dont really get it... why don't you just type the px ? is the font-size in body changing ?

Comment: I really doubt it's possible. The only relative quantities I'm aware of in CSS are em-% in fonts and % in width and height relative to the container

Comment: @Ace stacking up a div with 1.2em and a p inside with 0.8em will create a different font size, and therefore line-height than the p with the body as it's main parent...

Comment: @GiovanniSferro that's what I was afraid of. Wanted to asked here on stackoverflow to make sure.

Comment: you could set the `line-height` to the parent container (`body` in the example) and remove it from the element (`p` in the example) **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whvjd/)**

Comment: If you specify the line height on the parent container, its typically inherited by the child elements when using `em`, regardless of their font-size.  That won't help you with the margins/paddings, though, since those apply based on the current element's font-size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you could use the [`rem`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#rem-unit), though it refers to the font size of the `html` element (so you would need to use the `html` selector, not `body`, and let `body` inherit from `html`). However, browser support is limited.

So it’s a better idea to use the `em` unit, just taking into account of your other settings. If `p` has `font-size: 0.875em`, then to set a margin to a value that its the font size of the parent (calculating 1/0.875), you would use the inverse value: `margin-bottom: 1.143em`.

On the other hand, it is natural to regard the font size of the `body` element as the size of copy text, and `p` elements are normally copy text. So it would be more natural to set `font-size` of `body` (if you set it at all) to the desired copy text size. This would make things a bit easier.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=rem seems to have quite good support right now. Will check it out.

Comment: @VladNicula, lack of support on IE 8 means that for many years, `rem` won’t work for many people. And the `rem` unit would really be just an author’s convenience.

Comment: well I can't really set a 16px baseline on a 13px paragraph without rems. IE8 is not a targeted browser for what we're going to develop anyway, so we're good :D

Answer (score 1):

If you always know your parent element's size and your child element's size, then I can offer you a solution with Sass.

```
@function em2baseline($font-size, $size: 1em, $base-size: 1em) {
    $collector: ();

    @each $s in $size {
        $collector: append($collector, ($s / $font-size * $base-size));
    }
    @return $collector;
}
```

`$font-size` is the size of the child element, `$base-size` is a list of sizes relative to my `$base-size` (a list so I can use it with margin/padding shorthand), and $base-size is the size I want to make it relative to.

```
@debug em2baseline(2em);
// 0.5em

@debug em2baseline(2em, 1.5em);
// 0.75em
```

If you aren't into using Sass, you can still do the math on your own:

```
[size you want] / [child size] * [base size]
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I am doing now, calculating. The only difficulty is that for a 16px base font size, 13px are 0.8125ems, and then, to specify a lineheight of 16px form a 13px base size (of the element) it would mean setting the line-height to 16/13 which is not a good number. :)

Comment: For line-height specifically, Eric Meyer's article on "unitless line-height" may be of interest to you:  http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/